# Android WebView localStorage

Tags: android, webview, webkit, local-storage, webchromeclient

I'm attempting to get a HTML5 localStorage example working within an Android WebView (Webkit, ChromeClient). However I'm having no luck.  Everything works from the phones browsers just not from the WebView.

**Activity:**

```
public class BrowserActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public final void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        browser.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);        
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);

        browser.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + browser.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");

        browser.loadUrl("http://my.app.com:10099");
    }
}
```

**Manifiest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="RestrictedBrowser"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="RestrictedBrowser.BrowserActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

**Error**

> WARN/System.err(3961):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column packagename
>   is not unique (code 19) 07-12 13:57:43.425: WARN/System.err(3961): at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native
>   Method) 07-12 13:57:43.425: WARN/System.err(3961): at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:857)
>   WARN/System.err(3961): at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
>   WARN/System.err(3961): at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
>   WARN/System.err(3961): at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1665)
>   WARN/System.err(3961): at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
>   ERROR/SQLiteLog(28735): (14) cannot open file at
>   line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4] 07-12 13:57:47.005: ERROR/SQLiteLog(28735):
>   (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/NotificationPermissions.db) - 07-12
>   DEBUG/WebKit(28735): SQLite database failed to load from
>   /NotificationPermissions.db
>           Cause - unable to open database file 07-12 13:57:47.005: DEBUG/WebKit(28735): [  28735:28758 D/WebKit   ]
>           external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) :
>   bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create the database directory before you can use it.

Use the following code

```
String databasePath = browser.getContext().getDir("databases", 
                                   Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath(); 
browser.getSettings().setDatabasePath(databasePath);
```

Comment: http://static1.fjcdn.com/thumbnails/comments/Thanks+mate+_56900b0214b0eeee75bfd1b02b3574b1.jpg